# How to update all columns at once in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a database with 200 columns, how to update data from 21 to 200, not in this way  -

```sql
Set Column21 = NEW.Column21, 
    Column22 = NEW.Column22, 
    Column23 = NEW.Column23,
    Column24 = NEW.Column24,
    Column25 = NEW.Column25...
```

Comment: You seem to have the right idea.

Comment: why don't you use id ?

Comment: It's probably a table.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//You can loop through 22 to  200 and make the string or access property

let sql = "Set",i=22;
 [...Array(179)].forEach((_, l) => {

    let column = 'Column'+i;
    let val  = "some val"; //access value
    sql += ` ${column} = ${val} `;
    i++;
});
console.log(sql);
```